# Navigation bar disappearing when pushed programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I've been working on an app for a while now and it pushes a view controller from the AppDelegate. When it does the navigation bar that was previously on the view controller being pushed disappears. Right now it's a static nav bar (not part of a navigation controller), but it has been previously and still didn't work. What am I doing wrong? Is there some sort of workaround?

This is the code in the AppDelegate that I'm using to push it:

```
var storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
var PostView: AnyObject! = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("NewView")

var rootViewController = self.window!.rootViewController as! UINavigationController
rootViewController.pushViewController(PostView as! UIViewController, animated: true)
```

`pushViewController` is the one I'm trying to push.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

On the view controller that you are trying to push, on the `viewDidLoad` method, try to force the navigation bar to not be hidden

```
self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: false)
```

If this helps, check the view controller on the storyboard if you're not forcing the view controller to hides the navigation bar

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Added this to `viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)` since my navbar was disappearing from popping back from a push.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "NewStoryBoard", bundle: nil)

let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NewView") as! UIViewController

self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `rootViewController` is a `UINavigationController`. What ever view controller you push against this will use the `UINavigationBar` defined in that `UINavigationController`.

If you do not want the "automated" `UINavigationBar` that comes with `UINavigationController`, just must set some other type of view controller as the initial one (or set no view controller as initial).

Comment: My issue is not that I don't want to use a Nav Controller. It's that my NavController isn't showing up. Only the view without the nav bar is.

Comment: I want it there so that I can go back to the previous viewcontroller

Comment: And you are sure you have a UINavigationController as initial view controller in your Storyboard?